# VB.NET Crawler can't handle Single Page Applications such as AngularJS

Tags: vb.net, web-crawler, single-page-application

I have an existing web crawler (WinForms) developed using VB.NET for our SEOs which utilizes Web Requests. The application works fine on a regular website but when I try to crawl SPA sites (Single Page Applications), the application can't get a proper response.

```
    Dim siteBody As String = String.Empty
    Dim cleanedURL As String
    Dim wRequest As System.Net.HttpwRequestuest
    Dim wResponse As System.Net.HttpwResponse
    Dim rStream As System.IO.Stream
    Dim reader As System.IO.StreamReader

    Try
        wRequest = Nothing
        wResponse = Nothing
        rStream = Nothing
        wRequest = HttpwRequestuest.Create(urlList(i)) 'URL is being passed
        wRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        wRequest.UserAgent = "DummyValue" 
        wRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = False

        wResponse = wRequest.GetResponse()
        rStream = wResponse.GetResponseStream
        reader = New System.IO.StreamReader(rStream)
        siteBody = reader.ReadToEnd
        reader.Close()
        wResponse.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Dim passedBody = siteBody 'EMPTY RESULT
```

Based on the result, we will extract data and check for links and their status codes.

Comment: If the page requires JavaScript to run you'll have to run it to get the proper content. And that will practically require capturing the page from a browser.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But is it possible using WinForms?